# Convert a PHP class name to an index

Tags: php, namespaces

I have an array of namespaced classes

```
$modules = [
 Namespace\Folder\Module1::class
 Namespace\Folder\Module2::class
 Namespace\Folder\Module3::class
];
```

I want to be able to convert the class name into a unique index to be used and stored.

```
foreach($modules as $module) { 
  $index = someCleverFunctionHere($module);
}
```

I don't want to use md5 as that's too long.  I looked into using CRC32... and then decided against it.   I will be adding some text to the end of index and storing it in a table (the column is a length of 62 char), so the smaller the index is, the better.

$index could be alphanumberic or numeric.

I did think about doing a split on the class name and then building an index array

```
$indexArray = [
'a' => 'Namespace',
'b' => 'Folder',
'c' => 'Module1',
'd' => 'Module2',
];
```

Which would create an index for `Namespace\Folder\Module1::class`  as "abcc".

Is this the right approach?  If so what would be the best (and most efficient) way to convert the classname into the index?  If not... what do you suggest?

TIA.

Comment: _"what do you suggest?"_ Just use the class name.

Comment: I'm curious to why you want to do this.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That's also too long :)

Comment: So widen the field in the database.

Comment: Declare propety `index` in class manually and use it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone each class has a configuration array within it, for example a Facebook module might have an AppID setting.  These settings will then be appended to the class index and stored in the table. The column length is limited to 62 char, so I don't want to use a big index, just in case my setting names get a bit long too.

Comment: @DanMiller Yeah ... I was trying not to have to do that for every class.  But it's a valid option.

Comment: @AlexHowansky  It's wordpress core table.  Not too keen on messing with it.

Comment: `'_'.substr(hash('sha256', _CLASS_), 0, 61)`; :/

Comment: If you're having trouble trying to fit a class name plus its list of parameters into a single 62 character field, then your problem is not your hashing algorithm, it's your storage. If you don't want to touch the existing table, then just use the field's value as an fkey into a new table that contains your settings. As a bonus, you'll no longer be violating 1NF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
public static function getKey()
{
  $hashids = new Hashids();
  $className = static::class;
  if ($pos = strrpos($classname, '\\')) $classname = substr($classname, $pos + 1);
  return $className. '_' . $hashids->encode(crc32(static::class),7);
}
```

hashids (https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php)

This would convert (for example) `FlipMinds\Genie\Genie` into `Genie_n5YYRGM`